# pgfplots: How to add a straight lines to a spherical surface

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I have a sphere: 
[image]

I would like to illustrate: *The light lays in 1sec. a distance that corresponds to around 7.5 orbits around the world.*

So, how could I add (7.5) *circling lines* like this: 
[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis equal,
width=10cm,
height=10cm,
axis lines = center,
xlabel = {$x$},
ylabel = {$y$},
zlabel = {$z$},
ticks=none,
enlargelimits=0.3,
view/h=45,
scale uniformly strategy=units only,
]
\addplot3[%
surf,
%opacity = 0.2,
colormap={bw}{color=(lightgray) color=(lightgray)},% lines 1/2
ultra thin,% lines 2/2
color=gray!22,  % surface
z buffer = sort,
samples =33,
variable = \u,   variable y = \v,
domain = 0:180,    y domain = 0:360,
]
({cos(u)*sin(v)}, {sin(u)*sin(v)}, {cos(v)});
end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will recommend [Ipe](https://ipe.otfried.org/) for this picture.